# How to show this series has at most three nonzero consecutive terms and at least one not null?

Tags: analysis

Let $\psi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $1\leq \psi\leq 0$ and satisfying $$\psi(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}1&\textrm{if}&1\leq |x|\leq 2\\0&\textrm{if}&|x|<1/2\ \textrm{or}\ |x|>4 \end{array}\right.$$ For $k=1, 2, \ldots$ define $$\psi_k(\xi)=\psi\left(\frac{\xi}{2^{k-1}}\right),$$ and set $$\Phi(\xi)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \psi_k(\xi),$$ where $\psi_0\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ is such that $0\leq \psi_0(\xi)\leq 1$ and $$\psi_0(\xi)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl} 
1&\textrm{se}& |\xi|\leq 1\\ 0&\textrm{if}&|\xi|>2\end{array}\right.$$

**Question:** How can I show that for every $\xi\in\mathbb R^n$ fixed the series which defines $\Phi(\xi)$ has at most three nonzero consecutive terms and at least one is non zero?

**Obs:** Notice $$\textrm{supp}(\psi_k)\subset \{\xi\in\mathbb R^n: 2^{k-2}\leq |\xi|\leq 2^{k+1}\}.$$

Any help will be valuable. Thanks.

**Notation:** $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ consists of those $C^\infty$ functions on $\mathbb R^n$ with compact support.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  $\psi\neq0$, so $\psi_k\neq0$, so all of the terms are non-zero.  What do you mean by not null?

Comment: So $\Phi(5)=\psi_0(5)+\psi(5)+\psi_2(5)+\dots=0+0+\psi(2.5)+1+\psi(0.625)$ since all the other terms are 0. Is that correct? We don't know what $\psi(2.5),\psi(0.625)$ are, but it does not matter in this case, because we have just 3 non-zero terms. The question is how to show that is always true. Is that correct?

Comment: If so, it seems fairly simple. We have $8-8\epsilon,4-4\epsilon,2-2\epsilon,1-\epsilon,0.5-0.5\epsilon$ by successive halving and applying $\psi()$ we get 0,1,1,1,0.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that at most 3 of $\psi(2.5),1,\psi(0.625)$ are non-zero.

Comment: @almagest yes, that is the problem =) Notice given $\xi\in\mathbb R^n$ we might find $j\geq 1$ such that $2^{j-1}\leq |\xi|\leq 2^{j}$. I conjecture that in this case $\Phi(\xi)=\psi_j(\xi)+\psi_{j+1}(\xi)+\psi_{j+2}(\xi)$ but I can't show that (I don't recall if $\Phi$ would start with $\psi_{j}$ or $\psi_{j-1}$, but that is the idea, there would be only three terms left)..

Answer (score 0):

The information about $C^\infty$ is only relevant insofar as we do not know the value of $\psi(z)$ for $0.5\le|z|<1$ and $2<|z|\le 4$. Also the fact that the domain  is $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not relevant - we are only interested in $|z|$.

Suppose first that $|z|>4$. We successively halve $|z|$. The first term which is not definitely known to be zero comes when we get into the range $(2,4]$ for the modulus. The next term is in $(1,2]$ and we know that has value 1. The next term is in $(0.5,1]$ and we do not know its value. But all subsequent terms are in $(0,0.5)$ and so we know they are zero. Hence we can get at most 3 non-zero terms.

Clearly if we start with $|z|\le4$ we cannot do any better.